# Visual Studios 2017, "Basic Page" option not available

Tags: c#, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

I am running VS 2017 on windows 10, and am using the book "Head First C#" in class. I have also researched this topic online from several forums and youtude videos, but I have found no clear answer. I am attempting to create a new project as outline in my curriculum, but the option to select the "Basic Page" option inside the Add New Item dialog box is not available. There is the "Blank Page" option. How can I enable the "Basic Page" option.

Comment: And what are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming.

Comment: I suspect your version of the "Head First" book predates your Visual Studio version. And I think you mean "Visual Basic Web Forms Page" or "Visual Basic Web Page" instead of "Basic Page".

Comment: This is  a programming question. I am using Visual Studio 2017. I tried submit a screenshot but I didn't have enough points. Please don't be mean, I am simply asking for some assistance. Under the Add New Item, I only see Blank Page, and not an option for Basic Page. If you are not familiar with Visual Studio please don't try to insult me. I will ask my CS professor later. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the info for the book on Amazon says it's updated for Visual Studio 2013. You're using 2017, there have been many changes since then. If you want to do a 1:1 of the book, you'll need to get your hands on a copy of VS that matches the authors.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it by hand the old fashioned way. They removed quite a few options from the newest version, making a Basic page is one of the things removed.